# The LCM of three positive integers $X, Y$ and $Z$ is $119^2$. Find the number of ordered triplets $(X, Y, Z)$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

The LCM of three positive integers $X, Y$ and $Z$ is $119^2$.  Find the number of ordered triplets $(X, Y, Z)$.

My question is similar to:   [What is the number of ordered triplets $(x, y, z)$ such that the LCM of $x, y$ and $z$ is ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639275/what-is-the-number-of-ordered-triplets-x-y-z-such-that-the-lcm-of-x-y-a)  ,
but I am not able to understand both of the approaches provided there.

---

**My attempt:**

$119^2 = 7^2 * 17^2$ has total of $9$ factors

**Case 1:** When $119^2$ is one of the numbers.

Rest of the $2$ numbers have to be a factor of $119^2$

Case 1(a) :- $119^2 , a, b\Rightarrow\binom{8}{2}*3!=168$

Case 1(b) :- $119^2 , a, a\Rightarrow\binom{8}{1}*\frac{3!}{2!}=24=24$

Case 1(c) :- $119^2 , 119^2, a\Rightarrow\binom{8}{1}*\frac{3!}{2!}=24$

Case 1(d) :- $119^2 , 119^2, 119^2\Rightarrow 1$ way

Case 1(a), 1(b) are made using only one $119^2$, that's why I am choosing other factors from 8 options.

**CASE 1 : $217$**

**Case 2:-** When $119^2$ is not present in any number

Case 2(a):- $7^2$, $17^2$, $($a factor other than $7^2$, $17^2) \Rightarrow \binom{6}{1}* 3!=36$

Case 2(a):- $7^2$, $17^2$, $(7^2$ or $17^2) \Rightarrow \binom{2}{1}* \frac{3!}{2!}=6$

**CASE 2 : $42$**

I am getting a total of $217+42=259$ ways, but the answer is given as $361$ ways.
**What all ways am I missing?**

Comment: cases involving $7^2\times 17$ etc.

Comment: I believe $7^2*17$ is being included in the cases , for example in Case 1:- one of the 8 factors would indeed include $7^2*17$ , also in Case 2(a) a case with $7^2*17$ would be included

Comment: Huh?  Where did you count $7^2\times 17, 7\times 17^2, 7\times 17$ in your 2(a), for example?

Comment: Yeah I got ur point @user10354138, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### My Calculation :

Consider $7^2$ :
When $X$ or $Y$ or $Z$ have $7^2$ , then LCM will have $7^2$ , Else LCM will not have $7^2$.

Number of ways to include (or not include) $7^0,7^1,7^2$ will be $3 \times 3 \times 3 = 27$ , while number of ways to include $7^0,7^1$ (& not include $7^2$) is $2 \times 2 \times 2 = 8$ , Hence the ways we want are $27 - 8 = 19$

Consider $17^2$ :
When $X$ or $Y$ or $Z$ have $17^2$ , then LCM will have $17^2$ , Else LCM will not have $17^2$.

Number of ways to include (or not include) $17^0,17^1,17^2$ will be $3 \times 3 \times 3 = 27$ , while number of ways to include $17^0,17^1$ (& not include $17^2$) is $2 \times 2 \times 2 = 8$ , Hence the ways we want are $27 - 8 = 19$

Total ways will be $19 \times 19 = 361$

### Analysing OP Calculation :

Case 1 is Correct , though 1A & 1B can be combined like this :
$119^2,x,y$ where $x$ & $y$ have 8 ways , while we can order that in $3$ ways : $8 \times 8 \times 3 = 64 \times 3 = 192$
That matches OP way $168 + 24 = 192$

Case 2 is not Correct.
It is counting $7^2 , 17^2 , x$
It is missing Eg:
$7^2 \times 17 , 17^2 , x$
$7^2 , 17^2 \times 7 , x$
$7^2 \times 17 , 17^2 \times 7 , x$

### UPDATE [ DUE TO OP QUERY ] :

Let $A=7^0,B=7^1,C=7^2$.
We can make the numbers $X,Y,Z$ by including these numbers 3 times to $X,Y,Z$ like this : "AAA or AAB or AAC or ABA or CAB or CBA , ETC"

With that , how many ways ? $3 \times 3 \times 3 = 27$ ways.

In that , we always want C to be there , otherwise LCM will not have $C=7^2$.

Hence , we count ways where C is not there & remove those unwanted ways.

"AAA , AAB , ABA , ABB , BAA , BAB , BBA , BBB"

Without C , how many ways we have ? $2 \times 2 \times 2 = 8$ ways.

Hence , wanted ways are $27 - 8 = 19$ with $7$
Likewise , wanted ways are $27 - 8 = 19$ with $17$
Total ways are $19 \times 19 = 361$

This is Correct Method !

Comment: I am not able to understand why are we subtracting the 8 cases everytime

Comment: I have updated the Answer to respond to your Query , @VasuGupta , Let me know whether that is clarifying your Doubt !!

Comment: Thank you sooo much @Prem :) !!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Statement:**
Given that the LCM of three positive integers $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ is $119^2$, and the numbers $A=7^0$, $B=7^1$, and $C=7^2$ can be used to form $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, we need to find the number of ordered triplets $(X,Y,Z)$ such that the LCM contains $C=7^2$.

---

**Approach:**
The numbers $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ can be formed by using the numbers $A$, $B$, and $C$ in 3 different ways. This gives a total of:
$3 \times 3 \times 3 = 27$
ways.

However, for the LCM to contain $C=7^2$, we need to ensure that at least one of the numbers $X$, $Y$, or $Z$ is $C$. Therefore, we need to exclude the combinations where $C$ is **not present**.

**Combinations without $C$:**
The combinations that do not include $C$ are:
$AAA, AAB, ABA, ABB, BAA, BAB, BBA, BBB$

This gives a total of:
$2 \times 2 \times 2 = 8$
ways.

**Combinations with $C$:**
Subtracting the combinations without $C$ from the total, we get:
$27 - 8 = 19$
combinations that include $C$.

**Considering the Power of 17 (same as 7):**
Similarly, for the power of $17$, we have:
$A=17^0, B=17^1, C=17^2$

Using the same logic as above, we again get $19$ combinations that include $C=17^2$.

---

**Total Combinations:**
Multiplying the combinations for the powers of 7 and 17, we get the total number of ways as:
$$19 \times 19 = 361$$

---

**Conclusion:**
There are 361 ordered triplets $(X,Y,Z)$ such that the LCM of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ is $119^2$.